# Bootstrap 4 make part of form inline with label or fieldset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to 3 fields of a form horizontal (the rest of the fields will be stacked).

However it's not clear from the docs how the label of a field should be arranged. (their isn't an example in the docs which uses a label).

Here I'm trying to have a label to cover all three fields so happy to either use the label from the first two (and the other two fields have no label) or use a fieldset label instead.

I've done this, but the label seems to float too high,

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPWZzm

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="form-group mt-5">
    <div class="form-row ">
       <label class="col-2">Test </label>
      <div class="col"><select name="_units" class="form-control custom-select" id="id__units">
  <option value="s">s</option>

  <option value="£">£</option>

</select></div>
      <div class="col"><input type="number" name="usage" class="form-control" id="id_usage"></div>
      <div class="col"><select name="usage_period" class="form-control custom-select" id="id_usage_period">
  <option value="month">monthly</option>

  <option value="quarter">quarterly</option>

  <option value="year">yearly</option>

</select></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [inline forms](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms).

Comment: it's not the whole form I need inline just part of it

Answer (score 0):

I have added a fieldset-inline class to the fieldset (instead of the form-inline class) and overwritten the form-groups' display to inline-block.

```
.fieldset-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;

  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    .form-group {
      display: inline-block;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}
```